# Trying to verify a LDAP over SSL certificate, Server cannot be reached

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, ldap, ssl-certificate

I'm currently trying to connect to a LDAPS Server using the following VB.NET Code, which should set the right parameters and use the function seen below to verify the certificate when the Bind function is called.

The value of LdapHost is the IP, 10.100.11.10, and the value for LdapPort is 7636.

```
connection = new LdapConnection(new LdapDirectoryIdentifier(LdapHost, LdapPort));
connection.AuthType = 2; // Negotiate
connection.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = true;

connection.SessionOptions.VerifyServerCertificate = new VerifyServerCertificateCallback(VerifyServerCertificate);

//Both username and password are correct
connection.Credential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(strUsername, strPassword); 
connection.Bind();
```

This,
But upon trying to verify the Server Certificate, using the following code:

```
private bool VerifyServerCertificate(LdapConnection ldapConnection, X509Certificate certificate)
{
    try
    {
        X509Certificate2 certificate2 = new X509Certificate2(certificate);
        return certificate2.Verify();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new LdapException(9999, "Invalid certificate or path.");
    }
}
```

It Errors out at the Bind function saying that it cannot connect to the LDAP Server at all with the message "*The LDAP Server cannot be reached*"
Although upon testing the connection via PowerShell, the Server is available just fine.

**Is there something wrong with my verification method? Should I try a different approach entirely?**

Comment: I doubt that has anything to do with verification. Have you traced the connection using Wireshark to see what is actually happening? Also what type of server is it? A Domain Controller or just a LDAP server?

Comment: @Charlieface Oh hey, its you again :) I will try to see if wireshark has any more info, thanks. Also, its a Active Directory Domain Controller on a WIndows 2008 ( dont judge ) Server

Comment: @Charlieface I have to use Ethereal because wireshark does not want to work for some odd reason, but the results should be the same:
The packets are encrypted via TLS, but all TCP packes say that the TCP CHECKSUM is incorrect. Can that be an indicator of whats wrong?

Comment: Probably not the issue. Is there any other issue? If the client machine is in the same domain, try `new LdapConnection(new LdapDirectoryIdentifier(null, LdapPort))` which will get any available domain controller. Are you sure 7636 is right? The standard port is 636

Comment: Yes, the customer specified 7637. Locally I have set up everything as well, but with 636, so I can test it. My development machine is in the domain, and pings go through. I have now found a more concrete issue though: **The verify method above always returns FALSE**. I have already added the certificate to the windows certificate store though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the reason why the verification did not work.
Using

```
 X509Chain chain = new X509Chain();

 X509Certificate2 certificate2 = new X509Certificate2(certificate);
 var chainBuilt = chain.Build(certificate2);
 LogEvent("Val", 0, "Chain building status: " + chainBuilt);
 if (chainBuilt == false) {
     foreach (X509ChainStatus chainStatus in chain.ChainStatus)
         LogEvent("Val", 0, "Chain error: " + chainStatus.Status + " " + chainStatus.StatusInformation);
     chain.Reset();
     return false;
 }  else  {
     chain.Reset();
     return true;
  }
```

if the verification fails helped me understand that the **Root Certificate was not trusted on that specific server.**
Furthermore, it told me that it **could not reach the Revokation Server to check if the Certificate is still valid.**

This couldn't be checked though, since the configuration uses a **StartTLS certificate**, which does not have a Revokation Server.

Therefore, I added

```
chain.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags = X509VerificationFlags.IgnoreRootRevocationUnknown | X509VerificationFlags.IgnoreEndRevocationUnknown | X509VerificationFlags.IgnoreCtlSignerRevocationUnknown;
```

to ignore every property regarding the Revokation Server. It can now connect as intended.